# How to duplicate a row in a dataframe and relocate it just after the original row?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row

let's say I have this df

```
original_df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 22)
)
```

I wish the following output

```
  ID    Name Age
1  1   Alice  25
2  2     Bob  30
3  2     Bob  30
4  3 Charlie  22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat your row number in `[`:

```r
original_df[c(1, 2, 2, 3), ]
```

To make it more flexible, you can use `append` to create a new sequence of row indices.

```r
new_seq <- append(seq(nrow(original_df)), values = 2, after = 2)
original_df[new_seq, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this you can make a function based on the row number. In other words, duplicate the specific row based on the row number.

```
duplicate_row <- function(data_frame, row_number) {
  # Check if the row_number is valid
  if (row_number < 1 || row_number > nrow(data_frame)) {
    stop("Invalid row number")
  }
  
  # Duplicate the specified row
  duplicated_row <- data_frame[row_number, , drop = FALSE]
  
  # Add the duplicated row next to the original row
  result_df <- rbind(data_frame[seq_len(row_number), , drop = FALSE],
                     duplicated_row,
                     data_frame[-seq_len(row_number), , drop = FALSE])
  
  return(result_df)
}

duplicate_row(original_df, 2)

   ID    Name Age
1   1   Alice  25
2   2     Bob  30
21  2     Bob  30
3   3 Charlie  22
```